# Are there any mechanic tools that resemble an ice pick?

Tags: tools, tool-identification

A friend attended an an online lecture (unrelated to vehicle maintenance and repair) in which the instructor mentioned going into their mechanics toolbox to retrieve a tool that resembled an ice pick.

They made it sound like perhaps it had different heads with different diameters, and described the smallest one as "needle-like".

I can't think of any mechanics tools that resemble this description except perhaps an awl.

Any ideas what tool(s) to which they might have been referring?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds similar to the picks I've always used. Mostly I use them for removing clips, roll pins and also just digging at miscellaneous stuff. A set from craftsman has always been my favorite but I think it was discontinued. Same as these ones tho. There are other sizes/shapes but these 4 are the most common. Many places will call them "o-ring removal picks".

[image: picks]

Comment: You know, I have a set of those... somewhere.  I remember they have orange handles, but don't remember where I put them.  I think I would prefer to remember where they are instead of their color ;)

Comment: Yes, we have one of those lying around the shop for no reason, never used it in years, and it saved my bacon when I was trying to reassemble an alternator (to put the brushes in the "sprung back" position to let the slip ring get by).

Comment: One of my best purchases from the pound shop (you might call it a dollar store).  I actually used them to pick out seals too.  Not the aquatic kind.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  Scribes, punches, etc.  Many look like ice picks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does one use those for when working on automobiles that make them a better choice than an awl?

Comment: A genuine awl is a hand tool for woodwork or leather work. It isn't designed to survive being hit with a hammer, like a metalworking punch.

Comment: I have heard them called "prick" punch or "center" punch.